# How to write ELSE IF using ? : in javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, if-statement, append

I tried if else in javascript using ? : 
Ex :   `(i > 0 ? 'test': 'test1')`

But i need 
`if() {  }`
`esle if() {  }`
`else if() { }`
`else (){  }`
using ? : operators 
**Reason am using operators is am appending the table in Jquery so i need to write the logic in between append statements**

**can any one help me in this**

Comment: Why not use `switch`? It's easier to read and change/add code when needed.

Answer (score 5):

```
var value = Cond1 ? True1 : (Cond2 ? True2 : (Cond3 ? True3 : Other));
```

The `()` notations make the expression above clear, but not a must do.

Demo:

```js
var a;
for (var i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
  a = (i === 0 ? 'Zero' : (i === 1) ? 'one' : (i === 2) ? 'two' : 'Other');
  console.log(a);
}
```

However, I'd suggest use

```
var str;
if () {
  str = ...
} else if() {
  str = ...
}
// Or .append/.html  ...etc.
$TBL.text('....' + str + '.....');
```

For readability.

Answer (score 1):

With `switch` your code will be easier to read and it's also easy to add or change a `case`.

```
var i = 0;
switch(i) {
    case 0:
        //i is 0
        break;
    case 1:
        //i is 1
        break;
    case 2:
        //i is 2
        break;
    case 3:
        //i is 3
        break;
    case 'foobar':
        //this is not an integer
        break;
    default:
        //i is not one of the above
}
```

Comment: of course ternary operator is good when You've simple form: (condition)? iftrue : iffalse  . but everybody must agree that when we have complex conditions it's better to use switch..case

Answer (score 0):

You can use `iternary` operator in the following way to get the result:

```
Check_1 ? true_1 : (Check_2 ? true_2 : (Cond_3 ? true_3 : ....));
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use `ElseIf` condition in `javascript` like this

```
var time = new Date().getHours();
    if (time < 10) {
        greeting = "Good morning";
    } else if (time < 20) {
        greeting = "Good day";
    } else {
        greeting = "Good evening";
    }
```